# Using a function to move a user between View Controllers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, viewcontroller

I currently have the following function, once clicked, it takes the user to the ‘homeViewController’

```
func transitionToHome() {

   let homeViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.Storyboard.homeViewController) as? HomeViewController

view.window?.rootViewController = homeViewController
view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

}
```

However, I am looking to use this function when a user logs out to take them to the ‘UIViewController’, however whenever I use UIViewController instead of homeViewController in the above code, it produces the following error.

```
Type 'Constants.Storyboard' has no member 'UIViewController'
```

What do I need to do in order to make this work and take the user to the very first viewcontroller for the app?

Here’s the view of the view controller I am trying to redirect the user to.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the `Class` value from `ViewController` to `HomeViewController`, as well as the `Storyboard ID` to `HomeViewController` for the initialisation to work.

> Custom Class
>
> - Class `HomeViewController`
>
> Identity
>
> - Storyboard ID `HomeViewController`

Then can instantiate the view controller like this:

```swift
func transitionToHome() {
    let homeViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "HomeViewController") as? HomeViewController
    view.window?.rootViewController = homeViewController
    view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Comment: This didn't work, but I managed to reference the 'UINavigationController' instead and that worked! Thank you anyways though, it directed me onto the right tracks of using the 'Storyboard ID'.